# Android parse html save href links

Tags: android, html, parsing, hyperlink, href

I have an html string like:

One link is [sajfhds iufl](http://image.html)

How to convert this html string to string that contains links but not contains any html tags:
Result should be:

One link is http://image.html

Answer (score 0):

```
String regex = "^(https?|ftp|file)://[-a-zA-Z0-9+&@#/%?=~_|!:,.;]*[-a-zA-Z0-9+&@#/%=~_|]";

String regex = "\\b(https?|ftp|file)://[-a-zA-Z0-9+&@#/%?=~_|!:,.;]*[-a-zA-Z0-9+&@#/%=~_|]";

String regex = "<\\b(https?|ftp|file)://[-a-zA-Z0-9+&@#/%?=~_|!:,.;]*[-a-zA-Z0-9+&@#/%=~_|]>"; // matches <http://google.com>

String regex = "<^(https?|ftp|file)://[-a-zA-Z0-9+&@#/%?=~_|!:,.;]*[-a-zA-Z0-9+&@#/%=~_|]>"; // does not match <http://google.com>
```

Answer (score 0):

You will be having the string something like this

```
One link is <a href="http://image.html">sajfhds iufl</a>
```

What you need is

```
One link is <a href="http://image.html">http://image.html</a>
```

So, what you should do is find pattern using below code

```
//imports required
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

        String stringToSearch = "<a href = \"http://image.html\" > sajfhds iufl</a>";

        // the pattern we want to search for
        Pattern p = Pattern.compile("<a href\\s*=\\s*\"(.+?)\"\\s*>(.+?)</a>");
        Matcher m = p.matcher(stringToSearch);

        if (m.find())
        {
          String temp = stringToSearch.replace(m.group(2), m.group(1)); 
          //use the temp string for display
        }
```